# ngAnimate not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I'm trying to learn how to use ngAnimate with ngRepeat, but in my example, the items are just showing up instead of animating in.

I included ngAnimate, put it as a dependency in the module, gave my ngRepeat a class of item, and created the following.

```
.item-ng-enter {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.0;
  height: 0;
  left: 10px;
}
.item-ng-enter.item-ng-enter-active {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 1.0;
  left: 0;
  height: 18px;
}
```

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/EVFUww7dfUAJzQqth7mx

Answer (score 0):

First thing, Angular adds `.ng-enter` and `.ng-enter-active` classes so `.item-ng-enter` and `.item-ng-enter-active` are incorrect. Second thing you should be adding transition definitions in `.ng-animate` class which is added before any other angular class:

`.item.ng-animate { transition: all 0.5s ease; }`